# Monodromy groups that are profinitely dense in Sp(2g,Z)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties, arithmetic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$Assume $g\geq 2$. It is known that there exist finitely generated subgroups of $\Sp(2g,\mathbb{Z})$ of infinite index that surject onto all finite quotients of $\Sp(2g,\mathbb{Z})$ (see, for example, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1140.pdf)).

But can one such subgroup be the monodromy group of a family $f:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow B$ of principally polarized abelian varieties of dimension $g$ over a smooth projective complex curve $B$?